# How to interpret this Schoenfeld residual on scatterplot?

Tags: residuals, cox-model

I have used "partial residuals" on SPSS for the values on Y-axis, for gender. On the X-axis is the time to event (censored). When I plot this on a scatterplot, I get this picture below. Does this satisfy PH assumption in cox-regression model? How do I interpret this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot interpret Schoenfeld residuals without adding a nonparametric smoother to see the trend.  the plot you need is a smooth scaled Schoenfeld residual plot.  This is discussed in examples [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/index.html).  The plot estimates $\beta(t)$ as a function of $t$ (on the $x$-axis).

Comment: THanks for answering! How do I add a nonparametric smoother in SPSS? The link you are referring to is in R.

Comment: I've never used SPSS.  Not sure it's the best choice for survival analysis.